# Computing average of array of doubles in a vectorized way?

Tags: vdsp

Given an array V of doubles the goal is to compute the average A.

The usually recommended solution is something like:

```
double A = V[0];
for (int i = 1; i<N; i++)
{
    A = ((A * i) + V[i]) / (i + 1.0);
}
```

Computing an average of an array seems to be a common operation, yet I fail to find a function that would do that in a vectorized fashion.

All I found in vDSP is the [vavlinD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_vavlinD) function which computes arrays of averages, and cannot be retrofitted to compute the average of a single array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the right function in vDSP. It is [vDSP_meanv](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accelerate/Reference/vDSPRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vDSP_meanv).